# System.Linq error InvalidOperationException: on Queue.Average

Tags: c#, linq, unity-game-engine

Using a Queue to average a collection of 9 float values. Once in a while (it usually works!) I am getting the following error

> InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current
>   state of the object System.Linq.Enumerable.Average(IEnumerable`1
>   source)

The offending line is the last in this code excerpt

```
private bool OnPersonUpdated(IEvent evt)
{
    Event_Update castEvent = evt as Event_Update;
    if (castEvent != null)
    {
        if (peopleDict.ContainsKey(castEvent.id))
        {
            float xVel = castEvent.velX;
            GameObject cubeToMove = peopleDict[castEvent.id];
            if (xVel > 0)
            {
                float xPos = -1f * positionForPerson(castEvent.person);

                float dif = xPos - _prevX;
                if (dif < .5f)
                {
                    _posQueue.Enqueue(xPos);
                }
                if (_posQueue.Count >= 10)
                {
                    _posQueue.Dequeue();
                }
                float avPos = _posQueue.Average();
```

I realize without providing the complete application difficult to tell what is happening but what are some troubleshooting steps i should try?

Comment: If you are using a queue the collection is most likely to be used by another resource / thread. Without more detail on the queue object it's not possible to tell. But the error state that the object is not in a valid state and that can mean an object was added/remove while you where running the `Average` method.

Comment: I've updated my post with more code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens either (1) because your queue is being modified concurrently with the iteration; that is the only condition that causes queue iterator to throw `InvalidOperationException`, or (2) your queue has no elements, and the element type is non-nullable.

(1) Consider reference source code for the `Queue<T>` found [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/queue.cs,dad351e31516a06f). Here is the spot in the code throwing an exception (line 369):

```
if (_version != _q._version) ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource.InvalidOperation_EnumFailedVersion);
```

`_q.version` gets updated when `Queue<T>` instance gets modified; instance variable `_version` of `Queue<T>.Enumerator` class stores the version of `Queue<T>` at the time when you start iterating.

You can address this by adding some locking around reads and updates, or by switching to using [`ConcurrentQueue<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265(v=vs.110).aspx).

(2) Consider reference source code for `Enumerable<T>` found [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs). The code for averaging `float` (line 2002) and `float?` (line 2016) differ in the way they treat empty collections: nullable version returns `null`, while non-nullable version throws an exception. You can work around this by casting queue elements to `float?` before taking average:

```
float? avPos = _posQueue.Cast<float?>().Average();
```

Obviously, this change requires you to null-check `avPos`.

Comment: Though this case has different exception message than what was posted by the OP. And also, `Average` will throw `InvalidOperationException` when queue is empty (also with different message than what is being posted).

Comment: Thanks for the great help. I think my goal should be obvious now from my updated code sample >  to be constantly averaging a collection of the 10 most recent float values in an event loop. Will try ConcurrentQueue instead...

Comment: Unfortunately, mono framework doesn't seem to have a ConcurrentQueue class in it's mscorlib :(    https://answers.unity.com/questions/1375947/unity-error-is-inaccessible-due-to-its-protection.html

Can anyone help with re "adding locking around reads and updates" ??

Comment: @Evk It looks like mono has added concurrent queue support several versions ago. If you are on a version that is older than that, you could take the reference code, and use it in your own project. Adding locking would require going through all places where you use `_posQueue`, and adding `lock (_posQueue)` around the entire block of code that accesses the queue.

Comment: ok, found a custom Queue with lock for Unity https://gist.github.com/jaredjenkins/5421892

Comment: However missing an Average method.
Any chance someone can help?


https://gist.github.com/jaredjenkins/5421892

Comment: @eco_bach Try `_posQueue.CopyToArray().Average()`